# How to get the universal link domain of any app

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, mobile-development

I know that one way to open a specific app is by linking to them with their universal links.

For example opening facebook with 'fb://', or uber with 'uber://'

I believe these ('fb://', 'uber://') are called the domains or schema.

I was wondering if all apps have this capability, and if so, where or how to obtain the domains/schema of any given app, for both ios and android?

I am using flutter to open these links through the url-launcher, so once I have the domains/schema, opening the desired app is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about Deep Links, so maybe you need to read this article, it is just for android but for iOS it should be a similar process:

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Comment: So from what I've read, deep links are simply universal links that go past the home screen and to a specific page in the app.
Also, what you posted explains how to link to an app once you know it's schema, but my question is how do you figure out what the schema is in the first place?
In other words, they provide this link
example://gizmos
And I want to know where to obtain "example" given the app you are looking to open

Comment: I think that's possible only if the app owner share the deep-link, the other way is use a decompiler of the .apk and take a look into the Manifest.xml, but that way is a violation